# Storing passwords securely in MySQL, but still accessible by PAM

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, openssh, pam

We have a PHP application that stores passwords just using the MD5 function (with no salt).
We have OpenSSH set to use [pam-mysql](http://pam-mysql.sourceforge.net) to authenticate users from the same database.

We would like to switch to use hashed passwords and we are considering either: 1. doing it ourselves, (something like `md5($salt."$".$password)` or `hash("sha256", $salt."$".$password)`), or 2. using php's crypt function (which uses the OS crypt(3) if available).
The problem is that I have not found whether pam-mysql supports crypt(3) or any replacement pam module that does.

`crpyt(3)` uses a user supplied algorithm and salt: `crypt('password', '$5$saltstring$')` for `sha256` which returns `$5$saltstring$OH4IDuTlsuTYPdED1gsuiRMyTAwNlRWyA6Xr3I4/dQ5`. Any language that uses the `crypt(3)` library will see that string and know to use `sha256` with the given hash and expect the given result.

Is the first method sufficient or is there some PAM module out there that supports MySQL and crypt(3)?

Comment: this might be better asked on server exchange

Comment: `pam_unix` supports `crypt()` passwords just fine, sbeam.

Comment: @sbeam My understanding is that there is a difference between the executable crypt(1), which is trivial to crack and the library crypt(3) which is a standard wrapper around a number of cryptographic functions. Do you have information to the contrary?

Answer (score 0):

Use sha512, either a mysql implementation or a php implementation. If you use md5 you're using a known insecure function which opens you up to liability.

Comment: The md5 collision vulns you are thinking of are very slight; md5 is still fairly good and not in immediate danger.  However, sha512 is stronger, as you say...

Comment: `crypt(3)` is a system implementation of `sha256` and a number of other algorithms that any program can use.  You select the algorithm by the prefix of the salt. My question was not about which algorithm to use. I know about MD5 collisions, and I have worked on causing them in school.

Answer (score 0):

you may also use 3DES encryption for stronger security.